# Cannot resolve stream in Angular

Tags: angular

Once I updated project from angular 4 to 6, then I got the following error.

I wonder how to handle the following warning.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current version of `sax` has not fixed this issue you can try running `npm install stream --save`

Comment: This just hides the error, it is not a solution. That library is completely unrelated with the ```stream``` the other library is looking for.